# Magento Magmi Categories Import only

Tags: magento, import, export, magmi

I am trying to import/update categories using the module being developed for magento MAGMI, i have made my custom category csv file with columns:

1. Categories
2. ttf1
3. ttf2

2 and 3 are custom attributes, What i want to do is to update the categories different customly added attributes using csv file. And i get an error:

> String could not be parsed as XML

I thought my csv is not working perfectly, so i exported products csv from magento backend and try to import it, and it gives the same error. I need to import categories via MAGMI, i don't need to include any product data in csv. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magmi **does not import categories only**, it is able to create categories on the fly during item import that's a big difference. IE : magmi imports **ITEMS** and can auto create categories for **ITEMS** being imported.

If you want to import categories, use another magento plugin.

Answer (score 2):

if you want only import categories, you can create in MAGENTO (or via MAGMI) the product "test" with sku "0000" and import via MAGMI csv-file like:

```
"sku","categories"
"0000","NewCategory1"
"0000","NewCategory2/Sub1"
"0000","NewCategory2/Sub2"
"0000","NewCategory2/Sub3"
"0000","DeleteThisCategory"
```

in the end don't forget delete/disable the "test" product and "DeleteThisCategory" category.