# Cateogry create via magmi with no product

Tags: magento, categories, magmi

is there any way to create category via magmi without adding any products to the category ?

Also If any one have csv header to create category via magmi kindly share with me it will help me a lot..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1:**

Magmi does not import categories only, it is able to create categories on the fly during item import that's a big difference. IE : magmi imports ITEMS and can auto create categories for ITEMS being imported.

If you want to import categories, use another magento plugin.

See: [Magento Magmi Categories Import only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884246/magento-magmi-categories-import-only)

**part 2:**

Basic example:

```
sku;name;attribute_set;store;categories
"100";"Product 1";"Default";"en";"My Products/Sample Products/Sample Category"
"101";"Product 2";"Default";"en";"My Products/Other Products"
```

Defining category options:

```
sku;name;attribute_set;store;categories
"100";"Product 1";"Default";"en";"My Products::1::0::1/Sample Products/Sample Category::1::0::0"
"101";"Product 2";"Default";"en";"My Products::1::0::1/Other Products"
```

For more: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer